# Координаты долгота, широта и расстояние в км

Tags: php, google-maps

Есть две точки с координатами (долгота; широта). Как узнать расстояние между ними в километрах? Можно ли это сделать математически? Или может через Google API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл функцию в интернете, спасибо!

```
    function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)  
{  
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;  
    $lat1 *= $pi80;  
    $lng1 *= $pi80;  
    $lat2 *= $pi80;  
    $lng2 *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km  
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;  
    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;  
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);  
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));  
    $km = $r * $c;

    return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А я использую немного другую функцию, может кому пригодится:

```
function distance($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2)
     {
        // Convert degrees to radians.
        $lat1=deg2rad($lat1);
        $lon1=deg2rad($lon1);
        $lat2=deg2rad($lat2);
        $lon2=deg2rad($lon2);

        // Calculate delta longitude and latitude.
        $delta_lat=($lat2 - $lat1);
        $delta_lng=($lon2 - $lon1);

        return round( 6378137/1000 * acos( cos( $lat1 ) * cos( $lat2 ) * cos( $lon1 - $lon2 ) + sin( $lat1 ) * sin( $lat2 ) ),1 );
     }
```

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет сравнить